# How to view the original script that built a materialized view and that was created by another user?

Tags: oracle, permissions, materialized-view

In the Oracle database server use, another user (called `MIMIC2DEVEL`) created a materialized view and made it public. How to view the original script that was used to built it?

Here are the grants on the materialized view:

[image]

I am aware of [How to view the original script of a materialized view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17268963/395857) but the two solutions proposed there do not seem to work for materialized views that was created by another user.

I use Oracle SQL Developer and the database server runs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the owner in GET_DDL, or use ALL_MVIEWS instead of USER_MVIEWS:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', 'MVIEW_NAME', 'OWNER') from dual;

select query from all_mviews
  where mview_name = 'your materialized view';
```